# Performing an UPDATE with Union in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update, union

If I were to have these three tables (just an example in order to learn UNION, these are not real tables):

**Tables with their columns:**

```
Customer: 
id | name        | order_status

Order_Web:
id | customer_id | order_filled

Order:
id | customer_id | order_filled
```

And I wanted to update order_status in the Customer table when there is a order filled in either the Order_Web table or the Order table for that customer using Union:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.order_status = 1
FROM Customer AS c
INNER JOIN Order_Web As ow
      ON c.id = ow.customer_id
WHERE ow.order_filled = 1

UPDATE c
SET c.order_status = 1
FROM Customer AS c
INNER JOIN Order As o
      ON c.id = o.customer_id
WHERE o.order_filled = 1
```

How can I combine these two updates using a Union on order_web and order?

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: `Order status should not be in the customer table`. Table design is incorrect here. One customer can have more than one orders and each order should have their own status. So, `Order status should be in order table(s)`.

Comment: @Kaf, did you notice the sentence where he said they are not real tables?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You do not need a `UNION` for that - replacing an inner join with a pair of outer ones should do it:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.order_status = 1
FROM Customer AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_Web As ow ON c.id = ow.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order As o ON c.id = o.customer_id
WHERE ow.order_filled = 1 OR o.order_filled = 1
```

You could also use a `WHERE EXISTS`, like this:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.order_status = 1
FROM Customer AS c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Order_Web As ow WHERE c.id = ow.customer_id AND ow.order_filled = 1 
) OR EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Order As o WHERE c.id = o.customer_id AND o.order_filled = 1
)
```

If you must use `UNION`, you can do it as follows:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.order_status = 1
FROM Customer AS c
WHERE c.id in (
        SELECT ow.id FROM Order_Web As ow WHERE ow.order_filled = 1 
    UNION
        SELECT o.id FROM Order As o WHERE o.order_filled = 1
)
```

or the same one with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.order_status = 1
FROM Customer AS c
JOIN (
        SELECT ow.id AS id FROM Order_Web As ow WHERE ow.order_filled = 1 
    UNION
        SELECT o.id AS id FROM Order As o WHERE o.order_filled = 1
) AS ids ON ids.id = c.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the different methods. That was helpful, however I still want to know how UNION would be set up. For the sake of learning can you please include an example with an UNION of the two tables?

Comment: Thanks, @dasblinkenlight. The first and third options were really helpful for me.

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE  c
SET     c.order_status = 1
FROM    (
        SELECT  customer_id
        FROM    order_web
        WHERE   order_filled = 1
        UNION
        SELECT  customer_id
        FROM    order
        WHERE   order_filled = 1
        ) o
JOIN    customer c
ON      c.id = o.customer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your union query into a subquery.

```
update customer
c.order_status = 1
where id in 
(union query goes here)
```