# MySQL Update a Union Selection

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have the following SQL, which gives me the error that this union tabled called brokeredTable is not updateable.

```
UPDATE (SELECT chid,brokered,bid,uid,rate FROM spot_channels UNION SELECT tid,brokered,bid,uid,rate FROM tremor_tags) as brokeredTable SET brokered = 1, rate = 5, bid = 5, uid = 7 WHERE chid = 110399
```

As you can see the SQL is pretty simple, instead of running two update statements on two different tables I wanted to Union them into one set and then run the update against that set of data. Which apparently I cannot do this way.

Any Suggestions? Again I just want one SQL statement to accomplish this.

Comment: why even bother? start a transaction, issue two updates (one per table), commit the transaction. as far as the rest of the universe is concerned, you only did one query - the transaction.

Comment: That would work except I am processing this SQL through a prepared statement, which I did not include in my question. And doing prepared with transactions is more code than I prefer to write for this.

Comment: I have a sinking feeling the only way I can accomplish this is through a Join Hack. Looks like 2 queries it is, cause apparently SQL can only update 1 table at a time unless its joined.

Answer (score -1):

"The SQL UNION operator combines the result of two or more SELECT statements"

That query doesn't even have the UPDATE sintax. UPDATE table SET column = 'value'.
You should search before ask:

[Performing an UPDATE with Union in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818384/performing-an-update-with-union-in-sql)

Comment: First off since there is no common relationship between the two tables hence why they are unioned not joined. the link you provided only explains how to do it without Unions when two tables have a relationship and if there is no set where clause.

Comment: I usually go for the easiest way, so I would do it in two different queries but, have you tried to use the advice from that post like these?`UPDATE  brokeredTable SET brokered = 1, rate = 5, bid = 5, uid = 7 FROM (SELECT chid,brokered,bid,uid,rate FROM spot_channels UNION SELECT tid,brokered,bid,uid,rate FROM tremor_tags) as brokeredTable WHERE chid = 110399`

Comment: Unfortunately that is not valid SQL for MySQL

Comment: You have fields with same name in both tables, I guess you should do it in 2 separate queries.